# Group multi array by key and value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have an array like the one below

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "url" => "https://domain.com.vn"
      "value" => "Keyword B3"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "url" => "https://domain.com.vn"
      "value" => "[IMAGES 1]"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "url" => "https://domain-4.com.vn"
      "value" => "D1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "url" => "https://domain-4.com.vn"
      "value" => "E3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I want to combine the above 2 arrays into 1 array as follows (number of items in 2 arrays is always equal):

```
$result = [
    [
        "url" => [
            "https://domain.com.vn",
            "https://domain-4.com.vn"
        ]
        "value" => [
            "Keyword B3",
            "D1"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "url" => [
            "https://domain.com.vn",
            "https://domain-4.com.vn"
        ],
        "value" => [
            "[IMAGES 1]",
            "E3"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have searched a lot but have not found a solution yet. Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you removed some of the data? the number of items do not match.

Comment: can you show your first php array code. In short show us what you have done yet. atleast add some code for arrays.

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I've updated

Comment: Could you var_export() your data instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because number of items in 2 sub-arrays is always equal, you can use a for loop like this:

```php
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => [
      'url' => 'https://domain.com.vn',
      'value' => 'Keyword B3'
    ],
    1 => [
      'url' => 'https://domain.com.vn',
      'value' => '[IMAGES 1]'
    ]
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => [
      'url' => 'https://domain-4.com.vn',
      'value' => 'D1'
    ],
    1 => [
      'url' => 'https://domain-4.com.vn',
      'value' => 'E3'
    ]
  ]
];

$result = [];
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($array[0]); $i++) {
  $result[] = [
    'url' => [$array[0][$i]['url'], $array[1][$i]['url']],
    'value' => [$array[0][$i]['value'], $array[1][$i]['value']],
  ];
}

print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://domain.com.vn
                    [1] => https://domain-4.com.vn
                )

            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Keyword B3
                    [1] => D1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://domain.com.vn
                    [1] => https://domain-4.com.vn
                )

            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => [IMAGES 1]
                    [1] => E3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Not very flexible with hardcoded keys used in the process.

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic solution, you will need to iterate the first level of the array, then combine the first deep subarray's keys with the return value of `array_map()`'s special transposing behavior with `null` and the spread operator.

It sure is a bunch of voodoo, but it is dynamic.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YfcGK)) ([Demo showing different length first level data sets](https://3v4l.org/FiYFr))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($subarray) {
            return array_combine(
                array_keys($subarray[0]),
                array_map(null, ...array_values($subarray))
            );
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

See other other [php](/questions/tagged/php)[transpose](/questions/tagged/transpose) tagged Stack Overflow pages to see other usages of the transposing technique.